# how can i arrange duplicate entries in two columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel i have 5 columns (A, B, C, D, E) and rows (1 to 10). two columns (A and B) contains some matching texts- for an example lets say A1 and B5 has "Apple" and A3 and B2 has "Orange" now how can i arrange column B such that "Apple" and "Orange" text in the column B can shift to the same row as A (i.e. B1=Apple, B3=Orange), without disturbing other columns entries?

[[image: Before]]

[[image: Desired outcome]]

Comment: Once *Orange* has been moved from **B2** to **B3**, what should be in **B2** ?? ...............Do you want **B2** and **B3** to be swapped ??

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student - really appreciate your help!  i basically want all the rows from Column B to D to get arranged/sorted as per column A. So that means since A1 has Apple i want all the entries B5 to D5 to move up to B1 to D1. Likewise all the entries from B2 to D2 for Orange to move down to same row as A3.  Sorry if its not cleat enough? Thanks again!

Comment: is there a simple way to sort the entries from B to D matching what i have in column A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a non-VBA solution, you can use this formula and drag down:

```
= IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B$10,A1)>0,A1,IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$10,MATCH(B1,A$1:A$10,0)),B1))
```

See below, working example.

[image]

Of course, the disadvantage here is that the `B` column itself is not updated. A new column has to be created. If you actually want the `B` column to update, then VBA is required and I recommend using @Gary'sStudent's solution.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your updates to the original question, looks like you just want a basic `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

```
= INDEX(C$1:C$8,MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$8,0))
```

See below, working example. Note that there is no need to create a formula for what you desire in the `B` column, since it is already identical to the `A` column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImaginaryHuman072889. is there a way to sort all the items from B to D to match what its there in column A? All the Apple entries from B1 to D1 to move up to row 1 matching A1?

Comment: Beautiful formula !

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks!

Comment: @DeepakPrasad Please reword you original question, with pictures and/or example desired data, to *show* what you want to accomplish rather than explaining it in a comment.

Comment: @DeepakPrasad Another question worth asking is: Are you OK with having the result in a different column? If not, VBA is the only way to go. No sense in providing a formula-based solution if you are not OK with this.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - ok either way as long as get the desired outcome as shown in the picture. Thanks!

Comment: @DeepakPrasad See my edit. And if this answer works for you, please accept this answer by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on swapping entries.  Before:

[image]

and run this swap code:

```
Sub swap()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp As String, v As String
    For i = 1 To 10
        v = Cells(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To 10
            If v = Cells(j, 2) Then
                temp = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(i, 2) = v
                Cells(j, 2) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

results in:

[image]